# finding unkowns in Trignometry equation

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan(\theta + i \pi) = \tan(\alpha) + i \sec(\alpha)$, then what is the relation between $\theta$ and $\alpha$

1. $\theta = \frac{n\pi}{2}+\alpha$
2. $\theta = \frac{1}{2}(n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha)$
3. $\theta = \frac{1}{2}(n+1)-\alpha$
4. $\theta = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{n\pi}{2}-\alpha)$

How to simplify LHS or RHS to get the answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\displaystyle\tan(\theta+i\pi)=\tan\alpha+i\sec\alpha$

$\displaystyle\tan(\theta-i\pi)=\tan\alpha-i\sec\alpha$

So, $\displaystyle\tan[(\theta+i\pi)+(\theta-i\pi)]=\cdots=-\cot\alpha=\tan\left(\frac\pi2+\alpha\right)$

$\displaystyle\implies2\theta=n\pi+\frac\pi2+\alpha$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: nice argument. thanks a lot.

Comment: @GA316, My Pleasure.